# Help me understand the theory behind this? Find the circle between two given tangent equations

Tags: calculus

Problem: "Given two tangent equations; $y_1 = cx + d$  , $y_2 = ex + k$ , to a point $p(x,y)$, determine the circle between the two"

I'm meant to program this but I can't find information that is exactly the one for my case.

Calculus isn't my strength but I love to learn, I just need some guidance as to where to look at to get to my conclusion, or to have the theory behind it so that I can find ways to apply it.

Thanks in advance for any insight provided!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You want to find a circle between two lines at a point $x$?

Comment: @avid19 I believe so. Sadly I was unable to understand what was asked from me but the professor would not explain further (as he simply took it from a book and likely has no idea what it meant) I'm sorry if it doesn't translate very well, my mother language is Spanish so I'm directly translating as the problem was given.

So far I understand it as such, I'm given two tangents and asked to find the circle between the two at a given point X

Comment: Almost surely the statement is: _find a circle tangent to two given lines and passing through a given point_. If so, you have to find a point (the center of the circle) equidistant from the lines and the point. You need only analytical geometry: do you know point-point and point-line distance formulas ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Thank you for trying to help me understand this statement, the professor himself said "some statements may be badly redacted" so I'm assuming this is one of those.

As far as knowing these formulas, I do not remember them but I will surely look information regarding this topic assuming your statement idea is what was meant to be. Thanks once again!